# Windows 8 does not recognize USB Device at the remount after soft eject

Tags: windows-8, usb

I am trying to soft eject an USB Device by using tools (USB Disk Ejector, removedrive etc.). I call these tools from command line by my Java Program. These tools can eject USB devices successfully but after I remove USB Device and remount it, Windows does not recognize the ejected USB device on the same port. But the same USB Device can be recognized at the different USB port. Windows restart can fix the USB detection problem but this solution does not resolve my problem. I don't observe the same problem in other computer which runs Windows 7. My laptop runs Windows 8.

Thanks.

Comment: **Sounds like a problem with these tools.**  If you run these tools yourself, and they work, then its how your running them is the problem.  If the same problem happen then its the tools.  You need to determine which one it is.

Comment: I run these tools by myself also and they didn't work on Windows 8 but they did on Windows 7. This seems to be an Windows 8 problem.

Comment: So no matter how these tools are started they don't work on Windows 8?  This means they are not supported on Windows 8.